# Cursor on Tab - Javascript - Immediate field

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, user-interface

I have to modify an existing html / javascript code to move the cursor to immediately next field.

Here is the order of fields

Textbox 1
Textbox 2
Datebox 1
List 1
Textbox 3

When I enter the text in Textbox 2 and press tab, the cursor goes to Textbox 3.

I believe this is how it works by default. Is there a way we can control it using an HTML tag or something to make the cursor go to the field that's immediately after Textbox 2?

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`tabindex` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp). Set each element's tab index to a value corresponding to the order in which you want the user to cycle through them.